# Is this way of comment form validation safe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I wanted to add validation in my comments form in wordpress article comments, but I couldn't find a way to change the submit form (so that I could validate it on comment post submit). I've found a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-login-image-captcha/) that adds a captcha for user log in, so I took that, and added it to my comment form.

I've basically only added the shortcode to my comment form

```
function mytheme_image_captcha( $args ){

    // Adds an argument to the shortcode to record the type of form (Contact us, Request a Visit, Refer a Friend...) - [fuel-spam-guard form="Contact Us"]
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'form' => '' ), $args ) );

    // Create an array to hold the image library
    $captchas = array(
        esc_html__( 'Heart', 'mytheme') => "fa-heart",
        esc_html__( 'House', 'mytheme') => "fa-home",
        esc_html__( 'Star', 'mytheme')  => "fa-star",
        esc_html__( 'Car', 'mytheme')   => "fa-car",
        esc_html__( 'Cup', 'mytheme')   => "fa-coffee",
        esc_html__( 'Flag', 'mytheme')  => "fa-flag",
        esc_html__( 'Key', 'mytheme')   => "fa-key",
        esc_html__( 'Truck', 'mytheme') => "fa-truck",
        esc_html__( 'Tree', 'mytheme')  => "fa-tree",
        esc_html__( 'Plane', 'mytheme') => "fa-plane"
    );

    $choice = array_rand( $captchas, 3);
    foreach($choice as $key) {
        $choices[$key] = $captchas[$key];
    }

    // Pick a number between 0-2 and use it to determine which array item will be used as the answer
    $human = rand(0,2);

    ob_start(); ?>

        <div class="captcha-image">

            <p><?php _e('Please prove you are human by selecting the', 'mytheme'); ?> <span><?php echo $choice[$human]; ?></span> <?php esc_html_e('.', 'mytheme'); ?></p>

            <?php
            $i = -1;
            foreach($choices as $title => $image) {
                $i++;
                if($i == $human) { $value = "tn_human"; } else { $value = "bot"; };
                echo  '<label><input type="radio" name="tn_captcha" value="'. $value .'"/><i class="fa '. $image .'"></i></label>';
            }
            ?>

        </div>
        <div style="display:none">
            <input type="text" name="tn_honeypot">
            <input type="hidden" name="FormType" value="<?php echo $form ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="wplicic_exists" value="true"/>
        </div>

    <?php    // more code
    $result = ob_get_contents(); // get everything in to $result variable
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
}

add_shortcode('contact_captcha', 'mytheme_image_captcha');
```

which cycles images and words in input field that you need to select. The comment form is like this:

```
<?php

    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    $fields =  array(
      'author' =>
        '<div class="comment_fields"><p class="comment-form-author"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Name', 'mytheme' ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
        '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p></div>',
        'captcha' => (!is_user_logged_in()) ? do_shortcode('[contact_captcha]') : '',

    );

    $comment_field = '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Your Comment', 'mytheme' ) . '" cols="45" rows="6" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>';

    comment_form(array(
        'fields'                => $fields,
        'comment_field'         => $comment_field,
        'comment_notes_after'   => '',
        'id_submit'             => 'comment-submit',
        'title_reply'           => esc_html__( 'Leave a comment', 'mytheme' ),
        'title_reply_to'        => esc_html__( 'Leave a reply to %s.', 'mytheme' ),
        'cancel_reply_link'     => esc_html__( 'Cancel reply', 'mytheme' ),
        'label_submit'          => esc_html__( 'Submit', 'mytheme' ),
        'comment_notes_before'  => ''
    )); ?>
```

The captcha is shown only if the user is not logged in (I'm presuming that the logged in users are not robots).

So since I couldn't find a way to override the `$_POST` for the form submit, I added a small and simple js code that will disable the post button unless you click on the correct one. And it works

```
/*Comment Validation*/

if ($('#comments').length) {
    $('#comments').find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.captcha-image input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'tn_human' ){
            $('#comments').find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else{
            $('#comments').find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
}
```

Now my question is: how safe is this?

Can this prevent bots from commenting?

I have a feeling this isn't foolproof method of validating wordpress comments.

I found a captcha plugin that works, but it has a type based captcha (3 + __ = 7 type capthca), and the client asked for an image click based captcha, and I couldn't find a free one that will work on comments.

Any advice on safety is helpful.

Comment: There are 100s of free image based captcha available. Did you even search?

Comment: I searched, and I couldn't find one for comments that are free and have relatively good ratings.

Comment: Leave the ratings... You try it first and check.

Comment: Also I'm not looking for [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/screenshots/) type of image captcha. No typing inputs, only clicks. And all I seem to find under image captcha is like the one I posted...

Comment: What's wrong with [Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)?  They provide a simple and nice click-only solution.

Comment: I could use that, I just thought not to burden my client with another API they need to get.

Comment: no its not safe, unless you are validating the captcha server side, scripts actually just post the data to the page rather than using the browser to fill in the form. as regards free solutions, its probably better as a developer you create your own solution, i used to sub out work and terminated jobs in nearly 100% of the time if i found out they thought they could install a plugin to complete the job, why would i pay them any amount to install a plugin?

Comment: I guess I'll see how to implement the google recaptcha to be safe, I had a hunch this is not a safe solution :\

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for such scenario would be using a PHP library for captcha insertion into your form. It's the best practice because you don't have to grab a whole plugin just to use its shortcode for captcha.

I've recently used [Secureimage](https://www.phpcaptcha.org/download/) and it worked exactly the way I wanted it to be.

You'll have to insert the HTML elements for entry like this:

```
<input class="membership-form" type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" required>

<img style="margin-left: 34%;margin-top: 1%;" id="captcha" src="http://darpe.me/wp/wp-content/plugins/custom-register/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'http://darpe.me/wp/wp-content/plugins/custom-register/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>
```

Next, in your submit checking page, you'll add the following:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp/wp-content/plugins/YOUR-PLUGIN-PATH/securimage/securimage.php';

if (!is_wp_error($errors))  $errors = new WP_Error;
$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
    // the code was incorrect
    // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

    // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
    $errors->add('chaptcha_error', 'The security code entered was incorrect. Please try again!');
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks